# Struts error - can not find package

Tags: java, struts2

Having the error:

```
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport; package does not exist
```

I am using `struts2.3.8` and Not using eclipse or net beans, But have made this directory structure:

```
Code\Chapter\Struts2Application\WEB-INF\src\comm\kognet\action\ClientAction.java
```

and Unzipped `struts2` and copied and stored jar files in:

```
Code\Chapter\Struts2Application\WEB-INF\lib

common-logging1-1-1
freemarker-2.3.19
ognl3.0.6
xwork core-2.3.8
struts2 core-2.3.8
```

I have set `catalina_home` as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\apache-tomcat-7.0.37
```

Path as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
```

classpath as .

I am New to Struts and this is my first program. Please Help

Comment: add all jars set in class path

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing commons-io and commons-fileupload, and...
2. ...please don't try to do dependency management by hand: use Maven, Ivy, etc. and...
3. ...please don't do builds by hand, use Maven, Ant, etc.
4. Setting the classpath (using either the preferred `-classpath` or `-cp` or the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, which IMO should be avoided) to `.` is insufficient. You need to add all  your dependent jars explicitly, or via a wildcard, and...
5. ...you should add the output directory of your compilation so your own classes are available as well.
6. Don't put source into `WEB-INF`, use a directory outside of deployable artifacts. For toy development it's okay, but IMO it's a bad habit.

Comment: Thanks Dave, can you please explain How do I set classpath to add dependent Jar files ?

Comment: @user2245151 By following any Java tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your project name, right-click on it, select properties then select again libraries and classpath. There, you've just either add library or add jar/directory and voila!